# How do you compile a flutter application?

Tags: flutter

I'm seeing that I can introduce a compilation error in my dart code but `flutter build ios` will still successfully run. If I `flutter run -d [my-simulator]` the compile error will immediately be presented in a red screen on the simulator but I can't currently easily do this in a CI type check.

Is there are cli command I can run to ensure that all of the dart code is free of compile errors?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can run `dart analyze` or `flutter analyze` commands.

[More info](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/pull/61589)

Comment: Great! That's showing me `argument_type_not_assignable` errors that I was otherwise expecting to see in the build. Thanks!

Comment: You are welcome   @DavidPadbury